# get the time difference?

Tags: sql, sql-server

how do i compare the difference of 2 different Epoch Timestamp times, and then compare them both to differences in hours? while also returning the result of the differences between the two times?

for example we have these 2 different timestamps-

```
Epoch timestamp1: 1332516308 --being currenttime

Epoch timestamp2: 1335192846 --being currentime + a month
```

Comment: Sample data please. And work on your accept+voting rate: show some appreciation to those who answer your questions...

Comment: different Epoch?....what do you mean with "while also returning the result of the differences between the two times"?

Comment: Come on, give it more of a try, you are already so close!

Comment: guys please don't spam and go off topic, i wasn't aware of that system and i have also updated the post with example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select datediff(hh, dateadd(ss, 1332516308, '19700101'),dateadd(ss, 1335192846, '19700101'))
```

That should give you the difference between the time.

Answer (score 2):

you can use `DateDiff`

```
SELECT DateDiff(hh, '2012-03-22', GETDATE()) //difference in hours
```

more info at :

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx